# Turn image array to io bytes object to simulare open with 'rb'

Tags: python, python-requests, byte, opencv

I am trying to send frames of a video to a remote server using requests, the code I am using for the same is

```
def send_request(frame_path = "frame_on_disk_1.jpeg"):

    files = {'upload': with open(frame_path,"rb")}
    r = requests.post(URL, files=files)

    return r
```

So I am writing the frames to disk and then reading them as bytes when sending over to the server, which is not the best way to do it.

However, I am not sure how I can actually convert the array in the following code **represented by variable frame** in the code below, directly into a read byte object without touching the disk.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.MOV")


count = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imwrite(f"all_frames/frame_num_{count}.png",frame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and [cv2.imencode](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) to encode an image into a memory buffer.

I've also used a queue so the frames are enqueued and then HTTP requests are done in a separate threads.

```
import traceback

import cv2

from io import BytesIO
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

from requests import Session


URL = "http://example.com"
THREADS = 5
SAMPLE = "sample.mov"


class UploaderThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, s):
        super().__init__()

        self.q = q
        self.s = s

    def run(self):
        for count, file in iter(self.q.get, "STOP"):
            try:
                r = self.s.post(URL, files={"upload": file})
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
            else:
                print(f"Frame ({count}): {r}")


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(SAMPLE)
    q = Queue()
    s = Session()
    count = 0

    threads = []

    for _ in range(THREADS):
        t = UploaderThread(q, s)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        count += 1

        if not ret:
            break

        _, img = cv2.imencode(".png", frame)

        q.put_nowait((count, BytesIO(img)))

    for _ in range(THREADS):
        q.put("STOP")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I ll try it out today itself and revert back.